# Where does MongoDB store its documents?

Tags: mongodb

I have inserted and fetched data using MongoDB, in PHP. Is there an actual copy of this data in a document somewhere?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

MongoDB stores it's data in the data directory specified by [--dbpath](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#dbpath). It uses a database format so it's not *actual* documents, but there are multiple documents in each file and you cannot easily extract the data from this format yourself.

To read and/or update a document you need to use a MongoDB client, in the same way that you send SQL queries to MySQL through a MySQL client. You probably want to do it programmatically by using one of the [client libraries](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/) for your programming language, but there is also a [command-line client](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) if you need to do manual updates.

Comment: Oh I see, So say if I wanted to view the file and make an amend how could I do this ? Also where is my --dbpath defined ?

Comment: The best way is to update it through a MongoDB client (for example the Mongo class in PHP), in the same way that you send SQL queries to MySQL through a MySQL client. Otherwise you will have to implement their file format yourself, including such stuff as key generation and special datatypes, and you need to stop the MongoDB server before doing the update - this is obviously an insane solution.

Comment: Ahh I see so any update, delete etc should only be done via code in your chosen language ?

Comment: --dbpath is specified when you start the server, or in the configuration file specified by the -f or --config flag. Otherwise it have the default setting which is `/data/db`

Comment: OliverBS, that's right. There's also a command-line client if you need to do manual updates. You use the same language for updates in that client. You should read the developer manual to understand more about both the language used and data conventions: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Developer+Zone

Comment: If you are using MongoDB on Ubuntu, you can check --dbpath and other configuration options inside file /etc/mongodb.conf

Answer (score 32):

By default Mongo stores its data in the directory `/data/db`.

You can specify a different directory using the [`--dbpath`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo#StartingandStoppingMongo-AlternateDataDirectory,DefaultPort) option.

If you’re running Mongo on Windows then the directory will be `C:\data\db`, where `C` is the drive letter of the working directory in which Mongo was started. This is quite confusing, so on Windows I’d recommend that you always specify a data directory using `--dbpath`.

Comment: I am using v4.0.2, I installed the Mongo to C:\apps\Mongo. 
I didn't specify any path and the db path is located under c:\apps\Mongo\Server\4.0\data

Comment: For a deeper understanding: Where are the documents saved in? The only files that are large enough to contain my saved documents are the files in `/data/db/journal`, namely the `WiredTigerLog` and `WiredTigerPreplog` files. Are the documents encoded in there?