# Updating Part of String Without Querying Docs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, replace, mongoose-schema

`"dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "^5.2.8"
  }`

`"coverImage" : {
        "url" : "http://foo.com/media/hgfr2um5oqibs8lbjbv7.jpg",
        "size" : 0,
        "filename" : "hgfr2um5oqibs8lbjbv7.jpg"
    }`

Hi everyone. I'm trying to update url to `https://bar.com.s/media/hgfr2um5oqibs8lbjbv7.jpg` without querying doc and updating. Is there anyway to do it ?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6437345/6121568 I think you could find that string and replace it using OS code.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Emeeus thanks for the reply but I resolved my issue by another way.Here is my solution:

```
db.media.find({mediaContainer:"ContainerS3"}).forEach(function(e,i) {
    e.url=e.url.replace("//a.n.com","//b.n.com");
    db.media.save(e);
});
```

By writing this query to robomongo app. (Referenced from: [How to replace substring in mongodb document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589792/how-to-replace-substring-in-mongodb-document))